# file handling deleting record after 2nd use

Tags: java

when i run the program the second time my `Record.txt` gets empty .

i think i'm getting this error in the file reader but i dont know what to do with it.

if you guys can give me a hint i'll appreciate it.

```
File file = new File("D:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\program\\Record.txt");
if (file.length() <= 0) {
    try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(
                "D:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\program\\inventory.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String datas = "";

        while ((datas = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] d = datas.split(",");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(d[1]);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(d[2]);
            items.add(new list(d[0], a, b));

        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();

    } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

    Iterator itemit = items.iterator();
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(
                "D:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\program\\Record.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        itemit = items.iterator();
        while (itemit.hasNext()) {
            list l = (list) itemit.next();
            System.out.println(l.ingname + l.qty + l.ingid);
            if (item1 == 1 && l.ingid == 100) {
                l.qty = l.qty - item1qty;
            }
            if (item2 == 1 && l.ingid == 200) {
                l.qty = l.qty - item2qty;
            }
            bw.write(l.ingname + ":" + l.qty + ":" + l.ingid);
            bw.newLine();

        }
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
else{
            try{
                FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\program\\Record.txt");
                   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                   String datas = "";

                   //System.out.println(file.length());
                   while((datas = br.readLine()) != null){
                       String[] d = datas.split(",");
                       int x = Integer.parseInt(d[1]);
                       items.add(new list(d[0],x));


                   }
                   br.close();
                   fr.close();
            }catch(IOException | NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error? You need to capture the stack-trace in the catch block and not gobble it up.

Comment: have you used a debugger? How do you plan to read a file if its length is less than 0?

Comment: Please use the try with resources pattern so that your files and readers are closed even when an error occurs.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

From the code parts you provided it looks like the `items` list is only filled with entries from `inventory.txt` if the `Record.txt` file is empty. If it is not empty (f.e. when running the program for a second time) `items` is probably empty and thus the content of `Record.txt` will overwritten.

Currently your code looks like this

```
if (Record.txt file is emtpy) {
   read inventory file into items
}

write items to record file

// where is the corresponding if?!
else {
   read Record.txt file
}
```

and is should probably look like this

```
if (Record.txt file is emtpy) {
   read inventory file into items
   write items to record file
}
else {
   read Record.txt file
}
```

Comment: @Keii, please fix your code. After the edit the code is broken. And please use proper formatting. The way the code is currently "formatted" makes it hard to spot any error.

Comment: @Keii, note that the first if-block end just before `Iterator itemit = items.iterator();` but the code indention makes it look like the writing of the `Record.txt` should be part of the if-block. The added `else` makes no sense.